# Is it possible to get access to the HTTP Context from within a Sitecore Event handler?

Tags: sitecore

I am building a custom event handler for the Sitecore security:loggedin event.  Basically I want to run some code every time a user logs in.  Is it possible for me to get access to the HttpContext (application level variables, etc) from within the event handler code?  From what I can tell the only argument that is passed in is the User object for the user that just logged in.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is entirely possible:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    //do what you like
}
```